# Calculate an integral in polar coordinates

Tags: integration

I have to calculate the next integral in polar coordinates but it confuses me to calculate the extremes of integration. The condition $x> 1$ confuses me.

$\iint_D 6x dx dy$

$D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:y\geq 0,x\geq 1, x^2+y^2 \leq 4\}$

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain is the region bounded by a circle centered at the origin with radius $2$, the line $y=0$ and the line $x=1$ with the condition $x\ge 1$ that is

[image]

therefore

- $0\le \theta \le \frac{\pi}3$
- $r_{min}(\theta)=\frac 1 {\cos \theta}\le r \le 2$

therefore the set up becomes

$$\iint_D 6x \,dx dy=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}3}\, d\theta\int_{\frac 1 {\cos \theta}}^{2}6r^2\cos \theta \,dr$$

Comment: "The domain is given by an half of a quarter of circle" - not sure what this means, but it's either misleading or flat-out wrong - or maybe a typo and needs editing?

Comment: @NickD Yes it is not much clear in that way. I'm going to add a sketch! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The equation of a vertical line $x=k$ in polar coordinates is simply $r\cos \theta=k$, so the bounds for $r$ in the integral in polar coordinates are
$$\int_{\tfrac1{\cos\theta}}^2 ...\,\mathrm dr$$

Answer (score 1):

in polar coordinates $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$

also $x^2+y^2\le 4$

put $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$ in $x^2+y^2\le 4$ 
gives $r\le2$

given $y\ge 0$ and $x \ge 1$ thus   $y^2\le 3$

means  $r\sin(\theta)\le \sqrt3$

$2\sin(\theta)\le \sqrt3$

$\sin(\theta)\le \sqrt3/2$
thus $\theta \le \pi/3$

$$\iint_D 6x \,dx dy=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}3}\, \cos \theta  d\theta\int_{\frac 1 {\cos \theta}}^{2}6r^2\,dr$$